# android facebook sdk share-dialog setCaption is not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using  facebook sdk dependency 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'

I want to share a photo with some text. Here is the code i used from [reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

```
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .setCaption("my caption appears here")
            .build();
    SharePhotoContent photoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();
    shareButton.setShareContent(photoContent);
```

It doesn't show caption in share dialog and also not in post on facebook timeline.
How to post image with text on facebook wall ?

Comment: Prefill of message and caption is not allowed.

Comment: if not allowed, what is the use of setCaption() method ?

Comment: @WizKid i want to share a screenshot from my android app with a link to app on google play store. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't

Answer (score 2):

Wizkid is right. I was trying to do something similar and noticed that the setCaption() method did not work. 
Take a look at the android facebook sdk documentation in this link, and read the getCaption() method description:

"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/SharePhoto/"

"Gets the user generated caption. Note that the 'caption' must come from the user, as pre-filled content is forbidden by the Platform Policies (2.3)."